# Unable to load dependency from other workspace in Cargo

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm unable to add crate_b as a dependency to crate_a that's present in a different workspace.

I've below folder structure.

```
.
└── MainWorkspace/
    ├── Cargo.toml
    ├── crate_a/
    │   ├── Cargo.toml
    │   └── src/
    │       └── main.rs
    └── other_workspace/
        ├── Cargo.toml
        └── crate_b/
            ├── Cargo.toml
            └── src/
                └── lib.rs
```

The contents of Cargo.toml are as of below

`./MainWorkspace/Cargo.toml`

```ini
[workspace]
members = ["crate_a"]


[workspace.dependencies]
crate_b = { path = "other_workspace/crate_b" }
```

`./MainWorkspace/crate_a/Cargo.toml`

```ini
[package]
name = "crate_a"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
crate_b = { workspace = true }
```

`./MainWorkspace/other_workspace/Cargo.toml`

```ini
[workspace]
members = ["crate_b"]

[workspace.dependencies]
hello = { version = "*" }
```

`./MainWorkspace/other_workspace/crate_b/Cargo.toml`

```ini
[package]
name = "crate_b"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
hello = { workspace = true }
```

I get error running `cargo check`

```rust
error: failed to load manifest for workspace member `/home/akhil/project/foo/crate_a`

Caused by:
  failed to load manifest for dependency `crate_b`

Caused by:
  failed to parse manifest at `/home/akhil/project/foo/other_workspace/crate_b/Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  error inheriting `hello` from workspace root manifest's `workspace.dependencies.hello`

Caused by:
  `dependency.hello` was not found in `workspace.dependencies`
```

If I add `hello` dependency in my MainWorkspace's Cargo.toml file then it works.
Updated `./MainWorkspace/Cargo.toml`

```ini
[workspace]
members = ["crate_a"]

[workspace.dependencies]
crate_b = { path = "other_workspace/crate_b" }
hello = { version = "*" }
```

My question is why should `cargo` point to `MainWorkspace` Cargo.toml to find the `hello` dependency ? Instead it should depend on `other_workspace` Cargo.toml file.

Git repo to reproduce the error: https://github.com/akhildevelops/cargo-dependency

Answer (score 0):

Nested worspaces [are not supported](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/5042) and lead to weird errors.
Move the `other_worspace` out of the directory of the `MainWorkspace`.

<sub>Also consider rethinking your naming convention, it's all over the place with PascalCase and snake_case, just pick one and stick to it.</sub>

Comment: Haha.. Yaa that repo and code is just for reference.